# Updating Height/Width on canvas and restart draw

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

I'm playing around with `<canvas>` using JavaScript and I've hit a brick wall. JavaScript is not one of my strong suits to say the least so I imagine this problem is pretty basic and apologize in advance for not challenging your minds!

What I want is the `<canvas>` to update inline i.e `<canvas height="300" width="300">` to the same size as the view point of the browser, should they resize after the content has been loaded. I searched Stack Overflow and found plently of 'listening scripts' that I've tested. The ones I've tested resize the canvas but the animation seems to go bonkers. Below is the listener I'm using.

```
(function(){
    var
    // Obtain a reference to the canvas element
    // using its id.
        htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('world'),
        // Obtain a graphics context on the
        // canvas element for drawing.
        context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d');
    // Start listening to resize events and
    // draw canvas.
    initialize();
    function initialize() {
        // Register an event listener to
        // call the resizeCanvas() function each time
        // the window is resized.
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        // Draw canvas border for the first time.
        resizeCanvas();
    }
    // Display custom canvas.
    // In this case it's a blue, 5 pixel border that
    // resizes along with the browser window.
    function redraw() {
        updateScene();
    }
    // Runs each time the DOM window resize event fires.
    // Resets the canvas dimensions to match window,
    // then draws the new borders accordingly.
    function resizeCanvas() {
        htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        redraw();
    }
})();
```

And below is the animation code I'm using.

```
jQuery(function($) {
!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!
function(d, w){
    var FPS = 30;
    var F = 300;
    var N = 3;
    var VERTEX_MAX = 10;
    var TRAIL_QUALITY = 4000;
    var mu = 0.5;
    var bmRandom = function(mu, sigma){
        var x, y, r, tmp=null, tmp2;
        return function(){
            if(tmp !== null){
                tmp2 = tmp;
                tmp = null;
                return y*tmp2+mu;
            }
            do{
                x = Math.random()*2-1;
                y = Math.random()*2-1;
                r = x*x+y*y;
            }while(r>=1);
            tmp = sigma*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r);
            return x*tmp+mu;
        };
    };
    pointCopy = function(src, dst){
        dst.x = src.x;
        dst.y = src.y;
        dst.z = src.z;
        return dst;
    };
    Trail = function(pos, t, color_f){
        this.pos={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.goal={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_1={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_2={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start_time = 0;
        this.take_time = 1;
        this.vertexes = [];
        this.anchors_1 = [];
        this.anchors_2 = [];
        this.color_f = color_f;
        pointCopy(pos, this.pos);
        pointCopy(pos, this.start);
        pointCopy(pos, this.goal);
        this.setNextGoal(t);
    };
    Trail.prototype.setNextGoal = function(t, target){
        pointCopy(this.goal, this.start);
        this.anchor_1.x = this.start.x+(this.start.x-this.anchor_2.x)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.y = this.start.y+(this.start.y-this.anchor_2.y)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.z = this.start.z+(this.start.z-this.anchor_2.z)*mu;
        if(target){
            this.anchor_2.x = (this.anchor_1.x+target.x)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = (this.anchor_1.y+target.y)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = (this.anchor_1.z+target.z)/2+myrand();
            this.goal.x = target.x;
            this.goal.y = target.y;
            this.goal.z = target.z;
        }else{
            this.anchor_2.x = this.anchor_1.x+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = this.anchor_1.y+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = this.anchor_1.z+myrand();
            this.goal.x = this.anchor_2.x+myrand();
            this.goal.y = this.anchor_2.y+myrand();
            this.goal.z = this.anchor_2.z+myrand();
        }
        this.start_time = t;
        this.take_time = 200+Math.random()*200;
        this.vertexes.push(pointCopy(this.start, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_1.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_1, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_2.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_2, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        if(this.vertexes.length > VERTEX_MAX){
            this.vertexes.splice(0,this.vertexes.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_1.splice(0,this.anchors_1.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_2.splice(0,this.anchors_2.length-VERTEX_MAX);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.update = function(t, target){
        bezier3(
            t-this.start_time,
            this.start,
            this.anchor_1,
            this.anchor_2,
            this.goal,
            this.take_time,
            this.pos
            );
        if(t-this.start_time > this.take_time){
            this.setNextGoal(this.start_time+this.take_time, target);
            this.update(t, target);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.draw = function(ctx, camera, t){
        var i, dz, dt, ddt, rt, a, v={x:0, y:0, z:0};
        var ps = {x:0, y:0};
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(perspective(this.vertexes[0], camera, ps)){
            ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
        }
        var x0 = ps.x;
        rt = (t-this.start_time)/this.take_time;
        for(i=1; i<this.vertexes.length; i++){
            ddt = 0.01;
            for(dt=0; dt<1; dt+=ddt){
                bezier3(dt,
                        this.vertexes[i-1],
                        this.anchors_1[i-1],
                        this.anchors_2[i-1],
                        this.vertexes[i],
                        1,
                        v);
                if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                    dz = v.z-camera.z;
                    a = 1-(this.vertexes.length-i+1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                    this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                    ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
                }
            }
        }
        ddt = 0.01;
        for(dt=0; dt<rt; dt+=ddt){
            bezier3(dt,
                    this.start,
                    this.anchor_1,
                    this.anchor_2,
                    this.goal,
                    1,
                    v);
            if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                dz = v.z-camera.z;
                a = 1-(1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
            }
        }
        if(perspective(this.pos, camera, ps)){
            dz = this.pos.z-camera.z;
            a = 1-1/VERTEX_MAX;
            this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
            ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
    bezier3 = function(t, a, b, c, d, e, dst){
        t /= e;
        dst.x =
            a.x*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.x*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.x*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.x*t*t*t;
        dst.y =
            a.y*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.y*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.y*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.y*t*t*t;
        dst.z =
            a.z*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.z*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.z*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.z*t*t*t;
    };
    perspective = function(point, camera, dst){
        var dx = point.x-camera.x;
        var dy = point.y-camera.y;
        var dz = point.z-camera.z;
        if(dz > 0){
            dst.x = F*dx/dz;
            dst.y = F*dy/dz;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    updateScene = function(ctx){
        var i, goal;
        time_now = new Date().getTime();
        var time_d = time_now-time_pre;
        trails[0].update(time_now);
        for(i=1; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].update(time_now, trails[i-1].pos);
        }
        camera.x += (trails[0].pos.x-camera.x)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.y += (trails[0].pos.y-camera.y)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.z += (trails[0].pos.z-camera.z-100)*0.0005*time_d;
        time_pre = time_now;
    };
    drawScene = function(ctx){
        var i;
        ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(i=0; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].draw(ctx, camera, time_now);
        }
    };
    var myrand = bmRandom(0,20);
    var canvas = d.getElementById("world");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var trails = [];
    var i;
    var time_now = new Date().getTime();
    var time_pre = time_now;
    var camera = {x:0, y:0, z:-200};
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        trails.push(new Trail({x:myrand(), y:myrand(), z:myrand()},
                              time_now,
                              function(a,z){return "#FFFFFF";}));
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        switch(i%3){
            case 0:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,"+Math.floor(255*a)+",0,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            case 1:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 255,"+Math.floor(255*a)+","+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            default:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+Math.floor(255*a)+",0,255,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = w.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = w.innerHeight;
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    var loop = function(){
        updateScene();
        drawScene(ctx);
        w.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
    }(document, window);
});
```

To make it easier for you to see what problem I'm facing I've dumped the code into a [***JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/v5wf2h44/1/), give it a few moments after resizing.

How can I make the listener restart the drawing with the new size and without bugging like seen in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with this

```
 var loop = function(){
        canvas.width = w.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = w.innerHeight;
        ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        updateScene();
        drawScene(ctx);
        w.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5wf2h44/2/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for replying so quickly with a quick and effective solution!

Comment: just stubbled across a little bug I think, I was tabbed out of the window for 10mins and the animation stops when going back to the window, any idea?

Comment: @bybe this is by design. Browser throttle down rAF when tab is not active to save on things like battery. If you need consistency in movement you need to lock on time instead of frames (which is generally better in most cases).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg thanks for your response, does that mean I disable FPS using `//var FPS = 30;`?